# How to repair grub installation on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kali-linux, grub2

Hello i tried dual booting kali linux with ubuntu but this installation overwite my grub file I tried fixing grub using this and booting from live cd using this forum guide [repair grub](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?20559-How-To-Repair-Kali-Linux-Grub-With-Kali-Linux-Live-Cd-Dual-Boot-With-Windows-7)
I ran the command

```bash
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
exit
umount /mnt/dev/pts
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt
```

But chroot couldn't run /bin/sh on `/mnt`, `Error: No such file or directory`

I checked the mounted root filesystem and found out that
my /bin, /boot and other file system in / file system directory got moved to @ in the /.

how do i fix this safely without breaking my system?